# Seeking free satellite imagery basemaps to be used in webapps with frequent updates

Tags: data, imagery, satellite, basemap

I am looking for satellite imagery base maps to be used in my web application. I have been using Google satellite base maps, but they are very old. I need something which has frequent updates, weekly or monthly updates will work too. All I need is that it should be open source.

Comment: If you are looking for open data then [opendata.se] Stack Exchange would be a better place to ask

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a hard ask for imagery that is updated weekly/monthly without a concurrent subscription to a supplier.

Maybe this will help: https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

Comment: hello and thank you so much for your comment. This is a great resource for downloading satellite imagery. but what I want is a base map that can be used in a web application. just like some leaflet plugins of google satellite imagery. all these are not real-time or near real-time. they are atleast a year old imagery.